# Problema con numeros float en php

Tags: php, javascript, php5, float

que tal? ya se que es un tema bastante hablado pero no encuentro solucion posible aver si me podeis echar una mano.
Tengo una aplicación en la cual calculo el iva y como los productos que ofrezco tienen distindo iva he decidido sumar el importe y asignarlo en un array cuya clave es el iva que se aplica pongo un ejemplo:

```
$array_suma_productos = [
  "12.5" => 29,
  "21.4" => "30",                                                        
];
```

Aclaro que el iva no es el real ahora mismo no me acuerdo, el caso es que la clave esta en string y tengo que pasarlo a float por lo que hice lo siguiente

```
foreach ($array_suma_productos as $key => $value) {
    $key=(float)$key;
    $total[]=calcular_iva($key,$value);
}
```

El problema es que $key me da cero al aplicar float, ¿alguna solucion?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: No sé exactamente qué tipo de resultado final quieres, pero si haces esto por ejemplo: **`foreach ($array_suma_productos as $key => $value) {
    $total[]=$value*((float)$key)/100;
}`** tendrás en `$total` este array: `Array
(
    [0] => 3.625
    [1] => 6.42
)`. No sé exactamente qué quieres decir con que te da cero al aplicar `float`. En todo caso lo correcto sería, si usas la función, convertir a `float` dentro de la función, no fuera de ella.

Comment: En php 7.1.23 funciona bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, el problema era como guardaba la $key usaba el siguiente formato:

```
$array_suma_productos['"'.$imp.'"']='valor de la variable';
```

la manera correcta es la siguiente:

```
$imp=(string)$imp;                            
$array_suma_productos[$imp]='valor de la variable';
```

Answer (score 1):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

No sé exactamente qué tipo de resultado final quieres, pero si haces esto por ejemplo:

```
foreach ($array_suma_productos as $key => $value) { 
    $total[]=$value*((float)$key)/100; 
}
```

Tendrás en `$total` este array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3.625
    [1] => 6.42
)
```

Si quieres que quede asociado el IVA al monto, puedes hacerlo así:

```
foreach ($array_suma_productos as $key => $value) {
    $total[$value]=$value*((float)$key)/100;   
}
```

Tendrás:

```
Array
(
    [29] => 3.625
    [30] => 6.42
)
```

Y, si quieres todos los datos, agregas una nueva clave con el IVA calculado:

```
foreach ($array_suma_productos as $key => $value) {
    $iva=$value*((float)$key)/100;
    $total[]=array($key,$value,$iva);   
}
```

Tendrás:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12.5
            [1] => 29
            [2] => 3.625
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21.4
            [1] => 30
            [2] => 6.42
        )

)
```

Si persistes en querer usar una función. Entonces:

- No hagas la conversión en el bucle, sino en la función
- Verifica el trato que le das a los valores en ella

Por ejemplo:

```
function calcular_iva($key,$value){
    $key=(float)$key; //conversión aquí
    return $value*((float)$key)/100;
}
```

Y en el for, simplemente esto:

```
foreach ($array_suma_productos as $key => $value) { 
    $total[]=calcular_iva($key,$value); 
}
```

Comment: hola, gracias por tu aportación. si, el $total me interesa que quede asi porque luego aplico array_sum() y me queda el precio con el IVA calculado. He probado lo que has expuesto pero no se el motivo de porque al poner (float)$key el valor devuelto es cero en lugar de transformar la variable a float. Es la primera vez que me pasa eso y lo mismo si lo hago en la funcion calcular_iva() que es calcada a la que me has puesto. Gracias

Comment: @john_7573 muestra el código de tu función `calcular_iva` para revisarla, algo raro debe ocurrir en ella. La puedes agregar a la pregunta [editándola](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/214135/edit).

Comment: Estuve haciendo pruebas de diversas maneras y llego a la siguiente conclusion: si hago $key="20"; y despues le aplico echo (float)$key; me imprime 20 en una variable tipo double. Pero si en vez de $key="20" dejo el valor que pone en el bucle (el mismo, 20) al hacer echo me pone cero pero la variable sigue siendo double. El problema debe estar en en bucle no?

Comment: Lo curioso es que si hago lo mismo con $value funciona perfectamente